# What is the advantage of major-mode-remap-alist?

Tags: major-mode, mapping, aliases

I've had this in my init file about forever:

```
(defalias 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)       ;cperl is much nicer
```

Now I learned about `major-mode-remap-alist` in Emacs 29.1 which I had installed shortly after release. Should I switch to using it? What would be the advantage? There must be some, or else why was it added right?

Comment: The NEWS file mentions that `defalias` "can have undesirable side effects", but I don't know what those would be. `defalias` was the quick-and-dirty (the commit message calls it `crude`) method of redefining a symbol's function definition for major mode remapping, but having a purpose-built method probably leads to easier-to-understand (and therefore easier-to-maintain) code. That may or may not be compelling enough for you: I expect `defalias` to be a working solution for "ever", but it's better to keep up with the times IMO.

Comment: See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2022-09/msg02373.html for the bug report and the patch.

Comment: @NickD: Please post the relevant part(s) of Stefan M's message that you cited as an answer. E.g. *"the 'other' mode becomes unavailable, which is particularly problematic if we want the 'fancy/external' mode to be a derived mode of the other."* E.g., main reason: not making `perl-mode`, in the example, "unavailable".

Comment: OP: Consider filing an enhancement request (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) to have the raison d'etre added to the option's doc.